# ThreeJS: Can we skip the mouse event?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a mouse wheel event for zoom in/out in a huge model. What happens is when I scroll the mouse 3 times continuously the response (zoom in) happens very slow where it has some delay to zoom in event after the event is triggered. So what I what is when I scroll to zoom in 4 times and the first operation of the scroll is done I want to skip the 2nd / 3rd scroll delay and directly trigger the 4th scroll. Is that possible? I hope it can be achieved through setTimeout but I'm looking for any other suggestions are samples! Thanks in advance

Comment: You can just set the zoomSpeed of the controls. 
https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.zoomSpeed.

Comment: @AmriteshAnand Sometimes when we load some models the rotate/pan/zooming response will be slow even after when we trigger the event. So, even if the zoom spped are faster or slower the response will be slow always. We can set a interval to check the functionalities so that we can skip the event and call it again! I have done that but I have no idea how optimize it is!